# RecyclerView test scroll to position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm trying to figure out RecyclerView tests with espresso, I'm trying to use the `RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo` to scroll to the specified item in the RecyclerView .

```
onView(withId(R.id.rv_container)).perform(
    RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo<ItemViewHolder>(
        hasDescendant(
            withText("Item: 40")
        )
    )
)
```

This is the error I get.

```
Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to: holder with view: has descendant: with text: is "Item: 40"' on view 'with id is <com.example.endtoend:id/rv_container>'.
```

- Windows animation scale
- Transition animation scale
- Animator duration scale

are all turned off

I'm also not sure why I have to cast ViewHolder here, Android dev examples don't cast ViewHolder.

Aaron's trick to get the RecyclerViews ViewHierachy.

```
androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'not is displayed on the screen to the user' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: not is displayed on the screen to the user
     Got: "RecyclerView{id=2131231038, res-name=rv_container, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=1878, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=true, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@4b6b49e, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=532.0, child-count=12}"
```

[image]

ItemView XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rv_item_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:padding="8dp"/>
```

Comment: Can you try to replace `ItemViewHolder` with the parent class `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

Comment: I've tried that, I get the same error message.

Comment: Can you try to replace `withText("Item: 40")` with `withText("Item: 0")` (or any item that you are sure that is displayed on the `RecyclerView` without being scrolled

Comment: Oh, that's interesting, it returns the same error as the Item it has to scroll to.

Comment: Maybe your recycler view data was loaded asynchronously and Espresso went out of sync, or the view wasn't visible yet. Could you verify with a simple trick: `onView(withId(R.id.rv_container)).check(matches(not(isDisplayed())))`? It should print out current view hierarchy about the recycler view.

Comment: Nice Trick @Aaron I've included the results in my question. The child count is showing 12, which is the number of RV items currently displayed on the screen. Any suggestion on where to go from here?

Comment: It seems like the recycler view item is not a simple textview but rather a complex view which is why it's not able to find the matcher for `hasDescendent(withText`. Would you mind sharing the screenshot of your recyclerview?

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal I've included a screenshot of the RecyclerView, I don't think the Item View could be any more basic than it currently is.

Comment: @Shawn hmm everything looks right to me, not sure if i have missed anything.. how does your item view xml look like? If the root view is a TextView, you probably don't need hasDescendant matcher.

Comment: @Aaron I've included the ItemView at the bottom of the question and yes the TextView is the root view. Correct me if I'm wrong here but isn't the hasDescendant matcher starting in the RecyclerView and works down the view hierarchy until it finds a match.

Comment: @Shawn Aaron is right.. I think you need to wrap the `TextView` in a `ViewGroup` like `LinearLayout` to use `hasDescendant`

Comment: Moving the `TextView` into a `GroupView` has solved the problem. After knowing this was the solution, I re-read the `hasDecendant` documentation and I still read it as any view in the `ViewHierarchy` below the point of entry.

Comment: Nice, glad it's been resolved